# creating a class that pops up an advertisement image

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I have a tab bar controller and some nav controllers containing view controllers. In those view controllers I want to be able to have a timed banner that will animate up from the bottom of the view.

I started making a subclass of UIViewController with the images, but when I add it to my viewControlers it renders anything beneath it not clickable.

What is the best way of achieving this ad pop up and have it be reusable in all my viewControllers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the main view of this ad popup is not of zero width or height - banners from many ad networks will actually be displayed if you add them to such a view, but won't be clickable.

Also make sure the ad view is in front (bringSubviewToFront:) and, if you have a tab bar, try adding it to the main app's window, rather then to the current view. Tab bar can play tricks with Action Sheets (basically some buttons will be unclickable) which are solved by adding the Action Sheet to the main window. This may help with your popup ad views, too.